# MySQL BETWEEN two datetimes does not use INDEX

Tags: mysql, between

```
explain
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count, CreatedBy
FROM `Notes`
INNER JOIN Users ON UserID = CreatedBy
INNER JOIN UserRoles ON URoleID = RoleID AND RoleID = 1
WHERE NoteVisible = 1 AND NoteText NOT LIKE '%SOME KEYWORD%' 
      AND Created BETWEEN '2014-02-24 00:00:00' AND '2014-02-24 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY CreatedBy
```

[image]

As you see **ref** is NULL and goes through **23** rows instead of just going through **1** row. Now for this example this is fast but when I do range of 1-2 month the rows becomes **>10000** and it slows down the page alot and locks up tables.

**NOTE** If I remove the **00:00:00** and **23:59:59** then it uses index it only goes through 1 row but I need to select all data for entire day starting at **00:00** and ending at **23:59**.

Please help me restructure this query to fix this issue or suggest any possible solutions. thank you.

**EDIT**

Replacing **BETWEEN** by **<** or **>** or **<=** or **>=** does not fix the issue

Comment: What if you substitute `BETWEEN` for `('2014-02-24' <= Created AND Created < '2014-02-25')` ?

Comment: Already did that in different variations still does not use index

Comment: Please post structures of tables, or at least add prefixes to column names in the query, it's hard to guess which column belong to which table. Does `NoteVisible` belong to `Notes` ?

Comment: yes NoteVisible belongs to notes why would it belong to any presented tables?

Answer (score 4):

This query **uses** the index.
The select type is `range`, used key is `Created`

For range types, the `ref` column is always null, 
refer to documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html#jointype_range

> **range**
>
> Only rows that are in a given range are retrieved, using an index to select the rows. The key column in the output row indicates which index is used. The key_len contains the longest key part that was used. **The ref column is NULL for this type.**

(emphasis mine)

Comment: but there are not 23 rows in that range if I remove explain it only returns 1 row.

Comment: This is only an estimation - MySql thinks that there is 23 rows. It doesn't check an exact number of rows during the parse phase, it only estimates. But regardles of that, it thinks that it is better to use that index and join 23 rows than to use the primary key and join X rows.

Comment: Is there a way to fix the slowdown?

Answer (score 0):

when you are comparing a datetime field with strings in a greater_than/less_than comparison. If you use a cast or function (like UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) and transform also the other dates to unixtimestamp, that would do the trick but will destroy the use of the index. Maybe a better solution would be to store the date as unix timestamp in the table and put an index on that.

the other way ,you can add “limit” to your sql also worked for me